# how to use ifstream as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, parameter-passing, ifstream

When I create following function,

```
int readDataFromFile(ifstream&  openFileStream, Snowman data[ ]){
    double height;
    double weight;
    double temp;
    bool hat;
    string scarf;
    int count = 0;
    while(openFileStream >> height) {
        openFileStream >> weight;
        openFileStream >> temp;
        openFileStream >> hat;
        openFileStream >> scarf;
    }
    return count;
}
```

these parts are false;

```
openFileStream >> height;
openFileStream >> weight;
openFileStream >> temp;
openFileStream >> hat;
openFileStream >> scarf;
```

Results in:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream') and 'double')

I will open the `ifstream` in the `main()` function, but how to pass it to another function?

Comment: This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with passing `std::ifstream` to a function. Most likely you forgot to `#include` a required header file, but nobody will be able to tell you this, for certain, because the shown code fails to meet the requirements for a [mre], as explained in the [help]. See [ask] for more information. If you'd like further help, [edit] your question until complies with all requirements for a [mre].

Comment: Check that you have used `#include<fstream>` at the top of the file with the shown code and form a complete [repro] to edit into your question, otherwise there is only speculation.

Comment: take a look at my answer below. It should give you a clue where you might be going wrong

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at my snippet below which works on Windows. Note `ans.txt` just contains 2 double values

```
#include <fstream>    
#include <iostream>

void printcontents(std::ifstream& inp)
    {
        double val1, val2;

        while (inp)
        {
            inp >> val1;
            inp >> val2;
        }

        std::cout << val1 << " " << val2 << std::endl;
    }

    int main()
    {       


            std::ifstream inp("C:\\somefolder\\ans.txt");

            printcontents(inp);
```